# How can I find a family of m-r vectors that are orthogonal to an existing family of r orthogonal vectors?

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

I do not remember how to find/calculate a family of m-r orthogonal vectors that are orthogonal to an existing family of r orthogonal vectors.
Do anyone has an approach for such a calculation?

Comment: Have you done an elementary search? If you can find one your can repeat the process.

Comment: You wrote: `I do not remember`, which means you already seen this somewhere. Where have you seen this? How did you use to do this?